# How to prevent http get method and some post method on node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, post, get, httprequest

I am developing a server.
I want to prevent all Http get events and
some post events.
I just allow some post event (`/users`,`/login`,`/signup`...)
and I use node.js...

Comment: Just don't include any get method in your code.

Comment: you can use `request.method` on the incoming request obj to see what HTTP method was used (https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method). also, check out the `restify` library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create necessary post endpoint and handle other request as error, and provide message that method is not allowed.

Request Denied!!!